# change column values on page load with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My page contains a gridview called `gridviewDBFile`. The last column contains id's. I want to make those id's hyperlinked to a specific page, eg. `http://blabla.com?id=xxx`. My jquery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = "";
    $("#gridviewDBFile tr").each(function () {
        if (!this.rowIndex) 
            return;

        var values = $(this).find("td:last").text();
        var link = $("#testdiv").append("<a href=\"http://blabla.com?id=\">" + values + "</a>" + "</br>");
        list += link;
    });
    $("#testdiv").val(list);
});
```

Right now I am adding the list of values to a random `testdiv` for testing, but what I want is to change the id's to links in the last column on page load. Does anyone have an idea how to this?

Code on my .aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h2>ToolDB </h2>
        <div id="testdiv" style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -25px;">
        </div>
<br />

                 <asp:GridView ID="gridviewDBFile" runat="server" Width="600px"
                     PageSize="8" CssClass="Grid"
                     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                     PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
                 </asp:GridView>

</form>
```

Comment: Could you please add a small sample of the HTML to the question. We need to see what structure the data is in and where to retrieve information from.

Comment: added. I could make the Id's hyperlinked in the back end, but i need to do it with jquery if it is possible

Comment: `$("#gridviewDBFile tr>td:last").each(function(){var thisTd = $(this);var id = thisTd.html();var link = '<a href="http://blabla.com?id=' + id + '">' + id + '</a>';thisTd.html(link);})`

Comment: Seems like its working for only the last row column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gridviewDBFile tr").each(function() {
        if (!this.rowIndex)
            return;
        var values = $(this).find("td:last").text();
        var link = '<a href="http://blabla.com?id="'+ values + '>' + values + '</a>';
        $(this).find("td:last").html(link);
    });

});
```